# What can I do to get rid of the key logging trojan BNK?

Tags: windows, virus-removal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

My Windows security is telling me that I have this trojan Trojan-Bnk.Win32.keylogger.gen in my system. I have searched this trojan on another computer and it said that its a false alert and to down load Malwarebytes to remove it. However it wont let me onto the internet to download.

Comment: If its a 'false-alert' whats to remove?

Answer (score 0):

Before i go any further, i'd point out, the least troublesome way to get rid of the virus is a full system reinstall... but where's the fun in that?

Many viruses, unsurprisingly, tend to block anti malware sites - your best chance is to throw together a good set of tools onto a cd from another computer, and running them in safe mode. If this fails, i'd probably run a linux based anti virus live disk first - avira and kaspersky have some i believe, THEN run the anti virus tools in windows.

In addition to malwarebytes (if it dosen't install, something is wrong for certain), i'd probably suggest [gmer](http://www.gmer.net/) for detecting rootkits, and [combofix](http://www.combofix.org/) for its blunt force approach to malware removal.

Answer (score 0):

[**Trojan-BNK.Win32-Keylogger.gen**](http://www.precisesecurity.com/popup/trojan-bnkwin32-keyloggergen/) appears to be a [**scareware**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scareware) effect.

Don't install Anti-Virus software from anywhere -- it could be malware itself!

These are some links from other forums that might help.

1. [Got a Virus and a Complaint!](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/Got-a-Virus-and-a-Complaint/td-p/198482)
2. [Internet Antivirus Pro](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/Internet-Antivirus-Pro/m-p/65797)